# C - Methods of populating structures with static data

Tags: c, arrays

I am populating an array with data to be sent on the I2C, my code below shows what I am doing. To me this looks horrible. Is there a better/neater way that anyone can recommend?

Thanks

```
#define DS1337_SECONDS_REG              0x00
// Default values used for initialisation
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_SECONDS          0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_MINUTES          0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_HOURS_HR_MODE    0x40
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_DAY              0x00 /* Sun */
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_DATE             0x01
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_MONTH            0x01
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_YEAR             0x0C /* 2012 */
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_SECS        0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_MINS        0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_HRS         0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_DAY_DATE    0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_MINS        0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_HRS         0x00
#define DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_DAY_DATE    0x00

extern i2c_err_t i2c_send(const i2c_ch_t channel, const uint8_t data[], const uint32_t length, const i2c_stop_t stop);

rtc_err_t ds1337_init(void)
{
    uint8_t data_to_send[17] = { DS1337_SECONDS_REG,       /* Address of first register */
                             DS1337_DEFAULT_SECONDS, DS1337_DEFAULT_MINUTES, DS1337_DEFAULT_HOURS_HR_MODE,
                             DS1337_DEFAULT_DAY, DS1337_DEFAULT_DATE, DS1337_DEFAULT_MONTH, DS1337_DEFAULT_YEAR,
                             DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_SECS, DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_MINS, DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_HRS, DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM1_DAY_DATE,
                             DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_MINS, DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_HRS, DS1337_DEFAULT_ALM2_DAY_DATE,
                             DS1337_CTRL_REG_INIT_VAL, /* Turn off the squarewave output pin */
                             DS1337_CLEAR_STATUS_VAL   /* Clear the status registers */
                           };

if (i2c_set_address(DS1337_CHANNEL, DS1337_SPI_ADDRESS) != I2C_NO_ERROR)
     return RTC_I2C_ADDRESS_ERROR;

if (i2c_send(DS1337_CHANNEL, data_to_send, sizeof(data_to_send), STOP_CONDITION) != I2C_NO_ERROR)
    return RTC_I2C_SEND_ERROR;

//enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);

return RTC_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Pretty standard approach. Enums (instead of defines) won't make your source code much shorter. Hardcoding the constants in the code will make it unreadable. Having multiple calls to `i2c_send()` and no array will be about the same, though probably slightly bigger and less readable. Defining a number of functions to configure every little thing is a sure way to make the source code bigger. I'd probably just keep the code the way it is.

Comment: Comments are appreciated. As advised. I'm going to stick with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard approach. Enums (instead of defines) won't make your source code much shorter. Hardcoding the constants in the code will make it unreadable. Having multiple calls to i2c_send() and no array will be about the same, though probably slightly bigger and less readable. Defining a number of functions to configure every little thing is a sure way to make the source code bigger. I'd probably just keep the code the way it is.

Comment: Comments are appreciated, I'm going to stick with what I have.

Comment: @integra753: don't forget to mark *the* answer if you consider one as such.

Answer (score 2):

Use enums rather than #defines, and I would say "12" rather than "0x0C" for 2012.

Consider just hard-coding "0" in place of the apparently-unused `*ALM*` values.

`#include` a header file to get the declaration of `i2c_send()`, rather than explicitly declaring it.

Omit (i.e. make implicit) the `[17]` array size--just say `[]` and let the actual data you pack determine the size.

Comment: Consider just hard-coding "0" in place of the apparently-unused *ALM* values.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I only copied in i2c_send() so the api was clear.